# Bind Kendo grid in Angular on button's ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to display Kendo grid in angular upon button click. The `GetCustomer` function for `ng-click` is within `customerController`. If the code to display the grid `init()` function is called from the main controller then it displays data but not on button click.

The `var` in the `$scope` holds data but somehow the grid in the html markup is not re-drawn when called from event handlers. It's only displayed during the initial request of the html page. Do I need to wire up a promise or something?

I don't get any error in console but the grid is not re-drawn with data on button click. Any help would be appreciated.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deni_r/a2hLao6h/3/) link.**

You can uncomment the line `init()` available within `$scope.GetCustomer` and comment the `init()` available within the main controller to simulate the issue.

My html markup

```
<div>
<div data-ng-controller="customerController">
    <div kendo-grid="customerGrid" k-options="customerGridOptions"></div>
    <button id="submitCustomer" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-ng-click="GetCustomer()">Get Customer</button>
</div>
```

and my controller code

```
var app = angular.module("app", [
"kendo.directives"]);

app.controller("customerController", function ($scope) {

//init(); // this works

// I want the data to be bound to the grid on ng-click handler
$scope.GetCustomer = function () {
  init(); // this does not work
}

function init() {
    var customerData = [{
        firstName: "Joe",
        lastName: "Smith",
        status: "Active"
    }, {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Smith",
        status: "Active"
    }, {
        firstName: "Travis",
        lastName: "Smith",
        status: "Expired"
    }];

    $scope.customerDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: customerData
    });

    console.log('binding grid');

    $scope.customerGridOptions = {
        dataSource: $scope.customerDataSource,
        selectable: "row"
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that to work, you need to use the [`k-rebind`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#updating-widgets-when-options-change) attribute which makes the grid widget watch the given scope property for changes.

```
<div kendo-grid="customerGrid" 
     k-options="customerGridOptions" 
     k-rebind="customerGridOptions"></div>
```

(updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a2hLao6h/4/))

Comment: if I set  `filterable: true` or `sortable: true` or `pageable: true` then I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of null` in the console. Any idea how to get around it? I've updated the fiddle and is available here [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/deni_r/a2hLao6h/7/).

Comment: looks like a bug with k-rebind; if all you're after is changing the data dynamically, you can change an existing data source: http://jsfiddle.net/a2hLao6h/8/

Comment: Yes, it seems like a bug. Yes, I do want to change the data dynamically but during the initial page load the grid will be empty and will be populated based on some dropdown value changes on the page. Your above comment helped me, I'm planning to set  `data: [{   }]` during the initial load and on button click it will set data source to bind dynamic data to get around the issue.